# Spacer is stretched in Outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am using a `<div>` with `line-height: 1px` to make a line line like this:

```
<div style="background-color:#e6e6e6;line-height: 1px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Here it is in gmail:

[image: gmail]

But in outlook 2019 on windows it shows like this:

[image: outlook]

Does anyone know why this might be happening and if there is a fix? Thanks.

Comment: use a `hr` thats the intended use for that element.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the below as the tr and td elements are generally accepted by more email clients. Outlook in particular is a beast.

```
 <tr>
  <td height="1" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:1px; background-color:#e6e6e6;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```